# Apple Rejected New Version of App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

Hi can anyone maybe help me figure out what the issue is,

My second version of my app was compiled with `XCode 8.2` installed on my `Macbook`,
This week I made `three` changes to the app.

1) Added an `image` to a `view`
2) modified the method that uploads images to the server 
3) compiled with latest `XCode`

But they `rejected` it with the following message

We were unable to install the app on an iPad Air. The `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in the `Info.plist` is set in such a way that the app will not install on an `iPad Air` .

In my `Info.plist` file there is no `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` ( see attached `Info.rar` file with the `plist` file).

I ran the application on my `iPhone 5s` and it worked, I also ran it on the VS `Simulators (iPad Air 2, and iPad Air)` the `iPad Air 2` ran easily, the `iPad Air` hanged at the `Splash` Screen (I am doing no processing there), then it just closed, if I click on the app icon again it would hang again but the third time I clicked on the app it opened without issues

Here is my Info.plst
https://pastebin.com/bHscWVDr

I am using `Xamarin.iOs 10.8` on `Windows 10`
and I am using `XCode 8.3` on my `Mac Mini` with `OS 10.3`

EDIT 1:
the iPad Air Simulator is working normal now after I restarted my laptop, runs smoothly everytime

Comment: Have you used any third party library? if yes then check its plist file also.

Comment: No third party libraries used in the application

Comment: what capabilities are you using?

Comment: You can check https://pastebin.com/bHscWVDr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a demo video where you show that your app `compile/build` success and it works on the hardware or simulator.

Then in resolution center post the video to Apple review team.
Once they see your demo video they will most probably understand and approve your release.

It happens a lot (very frustrating) and its normal.

Comment: I have created a video, hope it works thank you for the answer so far

Comment: I did that, and they approved the app